# Using WCF Duplex Service Together With WCF RIA in Silverlight App

Tags: .net, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services, duplex

I've been using WCF RIA in my LOB Silverlight app quite happily for quite some time. I've recently seen some value in having the server initiate communications with the client, especially in situations where I initiate actions from the client that may take a very significant time to run on the server. Of course I prefer not to have to poll the server to death from the client to check whether the workload has been completed, it is much better for the server just to tell the client when it is finished processing.

The problem is that once I've defined the duplex service (using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027(v=vs.95).aspx as a guide), as soon as I try to add a service reference to my newly created duplex service using tcp bindings, all my auto generated WCF RIA types dissapear. One thing I notice is that I don't need to define any bindings for WCF RIA the way I had to for the duplex service. Perhaps I now need to specify them and not rely on the defaults? I'd appreciate it if anyone has managed to get these 2 to coexist and could let me know what needs to be done.

Comment: That is a fair question as I'm sure it can do what I would need. The duplex service however is also based on WCF (I'm already using WCF RIA in the project) and promises all I need provided that it can be made to play nice with WCF RIA. So that seemed the logical choice. I have the feeling it is just a small configuration issue, but if it turns out to be completely incompatible I will probably look at other options like SignalR.

Comment: Open RIA Services itself will be implementing this using SignalR as the default mechanism. Of course, Open RIA Services is itself moving to Web API instead of WCF, but that is a secondary consideration.

Comment: @ColinBlair That's interesting to know, and thank you very much for you ongoing effort for RIA Services.